# Edit user information in React

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using axios to get and post user information, but I am somewhat lost on how to handle editing a user's information. I have created a working put endpoint, but I am lost on how to change to editable text in React

User component:

```
const handleEdit = (user) => {

    axios
        .put(`/api/User/${user.id}`)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}

 return(
     <div className="container white">
         <h3 className="center"> 
         User List
         <Button className="btn-createUser" color="info">
             <Link to='/signup'>Add New User</Link>
         </Button>
         </h3>          
        <form className="inline-form">
             {users.list.map(user => (
                 <div className="section" key={user.id}>
                 <div className="divider"></div>
                     <h5 className="user-userName">{user.username}</h5>
                     <h5 className="user-userEmail">{user.email}</h5>
                     <Button className="btn-delete" color="info" onClick={() => handleDelete(user)}>Delete</Button>
                     <Button className="btn-edit" color="info" onClick={() => handleEdit(user)}>Edit</Button>
                 </div>
             ))}
        </form>
     </div>
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const [users] = useState([]); //declare users array at top then use setUsers to update


handleChange = event => {
   const index = users.findIndex(user => user.userName = event.target.value);
   users[index].userName =  event.target.value;
   setUsers(users);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set userName and userEmail in state first. the onChange method will capture new updates.

```
<input
       type="text"
       name="username"
       value={this.state.username}
       onChange={this.handleChange}
     /> 
handleChange = event => {
   this.setState({ username: event.target.value });
};
```

Comment: Now your axios method will have access to state variable. This is for one value.For object you'll have to set entire object.

Comment: I was using hooks for it. I understand the accessing part, but how when I click my edit button will my code change from simply text to say a textarea or input field?

Comment: when you click on edit button, just pass that clicked index object as props to detail page or so, where you might be using some textfield to provide edit. Or if you can post code of your detail page, I can see what's going on. We might have to pass callback function from parent to child.